# How does spark handle a Data Structure initialized outside of a DStream

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

How does spark handle a data structure that is initialised outside a DStream mapping and fill the data structure inside a `DStream.map`

Let's say we have a class called `Bucket` that consists of a `mutable.Queue[Double]`.

```
class Bucket() {
   def update(d: Double): Bucket
   def getBucket: Array[Double]
   def getFirstBucket: Array[Double]
}

class App {
   val counter: Long = 0
   val bucket = new Bucket(..)
   val inputStream = DStream[Double]

   inputStream.map(el => { 
      counter += 1
      bucket.update(el)
      if (counter == 1000) { bucket.getBucket }
     else { bucket.getFirstBucket }
    })
}
```

Is this `Bucket` distributed? I mean what will happen when I call `Bucket.update`?

Comment: It will serialize bucket and counter (if they're serializable, otherwise it'll throw an exception at runtime) per executor. This will probably not be what you want to do (assuming you want to share these counters between all executors in your app).

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov am guessing that each rdd will have a counter and a bucket right?